# an issue while trying to ensure the server is accesible (HostReachable)

Tags: android, android-emulator, ip

I want to check if server is reachable. Found an example here to get server's IP as integer value. Im trying to check it in following way (in activity):

```
    boolean s = isHostReachable(getString(R.string.server_address));
```

but no luck, it returns false, while

```
    final int serverIP = getHostIPAsInt(getString(R.string.server_address));
```

always returns a value. Here are the methods:

```
public static boolean isHostReachable(final String hostName){
    try {
        return InetAddress.getByName(hostName).isReachable(255);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e){
        return false;
    }
}

public static int getHostIPAsInt(final String hostname) {
    final InetAddress inetAddress = getHostIP(hostname);
    if (inetAddress==null)
        return 0;

    final byte[] addrBytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
    final int addr = (addrBytes[3]&0xff) << 24
                    | (addrBytes[2]&0xff) << 16
                    | (addrBytes[1]&0xff) << 8
                    |  addrBytes[0]&0xff;
    return addr;
```

also i tried the following with same result:

```
        isInternetWiFi = cm.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI, serverIP);
        isInternetMobile = cm.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, serverIP);
```

both are false even if i use "google.com". I got a feeling when serverIP is a negative value it always fails... But InetAddress doesn't use the serverIP and still returns false.
trying it with emulator (aos 2.2).
i need to ensure the server is up to continue executing app due 2 app's functionality depends on server (client/server app). But the idea was to check if the device uses (connected via) WiFi which has no real access to the internet like some local area WiFi. So i need to check 1st if server is reachable at all and the second - if it responds.
How2do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check if server is reachable.

Then make a real request. For example, request `robots.txt` from the Web server if you are trying to communicate with that Web server. Nothing else will be reliable -- your technique, even if it worked, would not work if the Web server daemon had crashed, for example.

Comment: "if the Web server daemon had crashed" - thats the additional reason why i wanna check the server. If server is down my app can't run cause its functionality depends on server. So i need to ensure server is up to continue executing app. But FOA the reason is to check if the device uses (connected via) WiFi which has no real access to the internet like some local area WiFi. So i need to check 1st if server is reachable at all and the second - if it responds.

Comment: What if server is not a regular http server (meaning some site hosting)? It just maintains some API functionality.

Comment: And in any case i don't like to request some file or something cause if server is down it will cause a waiting (timeout duration). And all this time app will freeze even if requests goes in separate thread. Thats because i cant go any further in app while it gets no response from server (log in for example).